# How can I suggest this project to the Stack Exchange documentation team?

Tags: support

First of all, I try to explain the context. I'm trying to update phpMyAdmin through SSH.

The tutorial suggest:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
```

Which is actually an instruction which maybe works or maybe not... I'm not sure if this folder change according to the Linux distribution.

But it would be very easy to change this string according to the Linux distribution. This could be done by a machine. And a machine could also easily explain what is the attempt of cd and /usr/ and so on.

The second tutorial instruction is

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.1/phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-all-languages.zip
```

Which is even more inaccurate because the latest version change and the wget command may change according to the distribution I guess.

All those problems may be solved by creating a **knowledge graph database**. And using it to analyze the instructions...

This could be used at the beginning to make the examples more universal and self explained.

Comment: I last messed with phpMyAdmin back in 2005, but just a quick look around suggests [that it can update from within itself](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/).  What value would a guide that you want to provide to do that hold in comparison to that?

Comment: @Makoto: one example relates to realizing that phpmyadmin.css.php 500 and phpmyadmin.css.php failed to load resource are actually the same research. A knowledge graph database may help a lot also in researches.

Comment: Today I've spent 6 hours reading articles like the one you have provided but it would be useful to have a framework for writing the article themselves. The idea is not very intuitive but when you write wget this is just a 4 letter words with no meaning. If SO would provide his Wordpress Plugin for code writing it could bind it to the new Documentation feature.

Comment: Can you tell me if you got what I said? I would really appreciate.. english is not my native language.

Comment: What I'm saying is...there seems to be a convention to upgrade phpMyAdmin that isn't through wget.  Why should Stack Overflow then add new infrastructure to support something *other* than Documentation to describe how one would go about updating and upgrading their installation?

Comment: @Makoto: phpmyadmin is just an example. Try to abstract. I will do another example. Think of every question asked on Stack Overflow. Nowaday it's possible to mark some words with links which suggest to check the documentation.

Comment: Having a Wordpress Plugin which tries to convert unstructured data (code examples) in structured data (aware code examples) provides an huge amount of links to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suggest features or ideas right here on meta. Describe what you want (in this case, describing the context is good, but you need to go into more detail on what exactly you mean by creating a knowledge graph database and using it to analyze instructions.

Tag your post [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) and it'll get on our radar.